# Get ID for a lazy many-to-one object withot database acces?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I wonder if this is possible,

i have a Class A with Id property of class B connected with lazy many-to-one relation.
And i want to get A.B.ID without connecting to database(For sure without loading whole B entity). Is is possible in NhibernatE?

A is many and b is One :)

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is the default behavior.  If you retrieve `A` from the database then access `A.B.Id` this will not hit the database.  If you access any other property besides the Id field it will cause NHibernate to retrieve `B` from the database.