# How to reference the class and Id properties of a relationship in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, foreign-key-relationship

Consider the relationship between these two classes

```
public class Order
{
  public int OrderId {get;set;}
  public int CustomerId {get;set;}  // Should this be here?
  public Customer Customer{get;set}
}

public class Customer
{
  public int CustomerId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I understand that I don't need the **CustomerId** property on **Order** and I agree that it is not the most beautifull OO way of doing things. Having only the Customer property, I could easily request **Order.Customer.CustomerId** to get the Id of the Customer.

But in that case, NHibernate will trigger a request to the database to load that customer and there are some (many actually) cases that I just need the **CustomerId** of the **Order**. In this case a **CustomerId** in the **Order** class would be usefull and would demand less trips to the database. (*If I am wrong about this, correct me please*).

**Question 1**: is there a way to tell NHibernate that I want both properties to be always updated?

The property **CustomerId** would always have the Id of the Customer and the property **Customer** would be loaded by lazy only if I want to (let's say to get the customer's name). Microsoft Entity Framework allows this.

**Question 2**: if it is not possible, should I worry about this?

**UPDATE**

Following the answers instructions I made a test trying to check why (in my case) NHibernate was not working as expected and found something interesting: *NHibernate will NOT hit the database by default at Order.Customer.CustomerId if **I don't use Accessor.Field mapping** the CustomerId property.*

With the default Accessor it works as expected. Any idea why?

Comment: You are wrong about order.customer.id firing a call to the database. I would recommend dropping your foreign key.  Therefore q1 and q2 are redundant

Comment: @Rippo: same comment I made in penfold's answer: I may be doing something wrong but in a test, A.B.Id did hit the database. Is something about the many-to-one mapping? Has it to be eager?

Comment: @RogerKiihl: Without seeing the mappings and test code it's not possible to tell. Please can you update your question with the mapping for these classes and the test code you used?

Comment: @penfold: I just updated de question. It worked but I found something unexpected. I thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of NHibernate is to not load an object when only accessing the Id. Another question has already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084553/get-id-for-a-lazy-many-to-one-object-withot-database-acces) which I have quoted below.

**If you retrieve `A` from the database then access `A.B.Id` this will not hit the database. If you access any other property besides the Id field it will cause NHibernate to retrieve B from the database.**

So in summary making the call `Order.Customer.CustomerId` will not trigger NHibernate to query the DB for the row in the customer table with that `CustomerId` and so it is best to remove the CustomerID from your Order class.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong but in a test, A.B.Id did hit the database. Is something about the many-to-one mapping? Has it to be eager?

Comment: After some tests I was able to verify that the answer is correct. But that default behavior works (still don't know why) when the mapped id property (Customer.CustomerId) uses the default accessor mapping.

Comment: @RogerKiihl I'm quite suprised about this as the access type should not affect lazy loading. The only thing that should effect it is `lazy="no-proxy"`.

Comment: thx anyway, I will check the official nhibernate groups to check if that is an error or by design

Answer (score 1):

Only one property can be writable. I suggest mapping of both like this (we are using this approach):

Class

```
public int CustomerId {get;set;}  // Should this be here?
public Customer Customer{get;set} // Answer: yes
```

Mapping

```
<many-to-one name="Customer" column="CustomerId"  />
<property  name="CustomerId" column="CustomerId" insert="false" update="false" />
```

Now you can manipulate with both properties in *Read* operations the same way (e.g. filtering). The bidning of the detached Order must set the `Customer`, while `CustomerId` is read only.

So for write operations, you can (and you should) use only one property.

The benefit is, that if you need to filter only by *Customer* `ID`, you do not have to manipulate the Customer (object, table) at all.

Comment: thx for the answer. I really wish that something like penfold answered would work (trying to). But your approach would help a lot!